# Pycharm debugging manage.py commands in docker compose

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have a pretty simple setup. I'm running Pycharm 2018.2.3 and using docker compose to spin up 3 containers.

1. My Django application
2. NGINX to serve static
3. Postgres DB

I've configured the remote interpreter for debugging the container, and break point work just fine in most cases, at least when I hit my API endpoints or some other action to the django application.

What does not work, is when I run one of my manage custom manage.py custom commands. I've tried this 2 ways so far.

1. I setup another debug configuration in PyCharm to execute the command. This results in another container spinning up (in place of the original. Running the command, without breaking on any line breaks. Then the whole container shuts down.
2. I've logged into the container, run the manage.py command directly via the command line, and it execute in the container, but again no breakpoints.

The documentation seems to work in the normal case, but I can't find any help for debugging these commands in the container.

Thanks for any help or tips.

Comment: So far what I think is working best is I'm simply tying my manage.py commands into a my API service. I can hit any of the commands I'd normally run with an API and the regular PyCharm Debugger, running inside my container works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update in case anybody comes across a similar problem. My personal solution was to not use the manage.py commands, but instead make these same commands available via an http call.

I found that it was easier (and often even more useful) to simply have an endpoint like myserver.com/api/do-admin-function and restrict that to administrative access.

When I put a breakpoint in my code, even running in the container, it breaks just fine as expected and allows me to debug the way I'd like

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug Django commands in a Docker Container you can create a new Run/Debug Configuration with following setup:

1. Use a Python configuration template
2. Script path: absolut location of `manage.py`
3. Parameters: the Django command you want to debug/execute
4. `!important!` Python interpreter: [Docker Compose interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#docker-compose-remote)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can depends on your `docker-compose.yml` exact content.

See for instance the section "[**An interactive debugger inside a running container!**](https://medium.com/zeitcode/a-simple-recipe-for-django-development-in-docker-bonus-testing-with-selenium-6a038ec19ba5#aa00)" of the article "**[A Simple Recipe for Django Development In Docker (Bonus: Testing with Selenium)](https://medium.com/zeitcode/a-simple-recipe-for-django-development-in-docker-bonus-testing-with-selenium-6a038ec19ba5#aa00)**" from [**Adam King**](https://twitter.com/adamking0126).

His `docker-compose.ym`l includes:

```
version: "2"
services:
  django:
    container_name: django_server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: docker_tutorial_django
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/myproject
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

In it, see:

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

> [Those 2 lines] are important, because they let us run an interactive terminal.
>   Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to kill the server running in your terminal, and then bring it up in the background with `docker-compose up -d`.
>   `docker ps` tells us it’s still running:
>
> We need to attach to that running container, in order to see its server output and pdb breakpoints.
>   The command `docker attach django_server` will present you with a blank line, but if you refresh your web browser, you’ll see the server output.
>   Drop `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in your code and you’ll get the interactive debugger, just like you’re used to.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe that even without adding the options in the docker compose (which I don't have), I can still get an interactive terminal by doing a docker attach -it /bin/sh for example. But I'm trying to get the PyCharm IDE debugger to break when running the manage.py commands. I don't use any pbd code as it stands now. Is that required only get to get manage.py commands to break in the editor?

Comment: @G.Ball Not required for local application, but for remote ones... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22623